# How to check function is called from which view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this field called Mobile_Number in my class Friends

```
[Remote("CheckMobileDuplicate", "Friends", ErrorMessage = "This mobile number is already in use", AdditionalFields = "Friend_Id")]
        public string Mobile_Number { get; set; }
```

Now there are 2 views in which post back occurs for the model class Friends, Create view and an edit view.

My CheckMobileDuplicate function is as follows

```
public JsonResult CheckMobileDuplicate(string Mobile_Number,int Friend_Id)
        {

                if (db.Friends.Any(x => (x.Mobile_Number == Mobile_Number) && (x.Friend_Id != Friend_Id))
                    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                else
                    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Now the condition `x.Friend_Id != Friend_Id`

Checks if the Friend_Id already exists so when we are checking in edit view it does not compare the mobile_number to the mobile_number of the same friend in the database.

But in create the Friend_Id is undefined as the row in database table is not yet created and hence this is not working for create.

So how do I check in the function whether it is called from create view or edit view because making Friend_Id nullable  is not an option ?

Comment: Best option: Create 2 separate view models with different `[Remote]` attributes. Another option: Make the parameter `Int? Friend_Id`, (you do not have to change the model) and check `If(Friend_Id.HasValue)` - if it has then you know know your editing an existing `Friend`, otherwise your creating a new `Friend` and can adjust the query accordingly

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am using database first and Friend_Id is defined in domain model so every time I update the database it will overwrite the code I have modified so how do I make it nullable

Comment: Did you read my first comment? Both options work. And what do you mean _it will overwrite the code_?

Comment: When update edmx from database occurs then it will rewrite the code in my domain model classes

Comment: And I if I create separate view models for create and edit I will have to change a lot of code because currently my controllers and views for create and edit are based on this single domain model

Comment: What - have you seriously applied a `RemoteAttribute` to your data model? That is a view specific validation attribute and should only be applied to a view model.

Comment: So any design advise would be really appreciated

Comment: And you can use just one view model (where property `FriendID` is `int?`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103669/discussion-between-mohit-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a view model for this. The `RemoteAttribute` is a view specific attribute and does not belong in a data model.

```
public class FriendsVM
{
    public int? Friend_Id { get; set; }
    [Remote("CheckMobileDuplicate", "Friends", ErrorMessage = "...", AdditionalFields = "Friend_Id")]
    public string Mobile_Number { get; set; }
    .... // other properties of Friend
}
```

and then in the view, add a hidden input for `Friend_Id`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Friend_Id)
```

and modify the controller method to

```
public JsonResult CheckMobileDuplicate(string Mobile_Number, int? Friend_Id)
{
    bool isUnique = IsUniqueMobile(Mobile_Number, Friend_Id);
    return Json(isUnique, JsonRequestBehavior);
}
private bool IsUniqueMobile(string number, int? ID)
{
    if (ID.hasValue) // its an existing Friend
    {
        return !db.Friends.Any(x => x.Mobile_Number == number && x.Friend_Id != ID.Value);
    }
    else // its a new Friend
    {
        return !db.Friends.Any(x => x.Mobile_Number == number);
    }
}
```

Note that I have refactored the database access code into a private method, so that method can also be called in the POST method